# Outlook causes gaps in between images

Tags: html, email, outlook

Getting gaps in between images in Outlook <2007, have tried all the usual things like line-height trick,  height as image heights

Below is the code. Works fine in all major email clients just Outlook causing the gaps

```
<table width="579" id="body" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="579" style="line-height:6px">
            <img src="http://media.pet-insurance.co.uk/email/test/pet/index_11.jpg" width="579" height="6"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="579" style="line-height:109px">
            <img src="http://media.pet-insurance.co.uk/email/test/pet/index_12.jpg" width="579" height="109"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What it looks like in Outlook <2007:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Resolved - Outlook doesn't like TD heights less than 15px so made them the ideal size